# Unable to connect to the remote server error

Tags: asp.net, email, smtp

i recently got the error :ystem.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Failure sending mail. ---> System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException.
And I naver go this before , it worked fine for just 2 weeks ago
my C# server side code:

```
MailMessage myEmail = new MailMessage()
                    {
                        Subject = "Message from website user:" + Name + "",
                        Body = "Email Address: " + email + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + "Message:" + Environment.NewLine + message,
                        IsBodyHtml = false,
                        From = new MailAddress(email, Name)
                    };

                    myEmail.To.Add(new MailAddress("yakov_mora@gmail.com‏"));
                    SmtpClient server = new SmtpClient();
                    server.Port = 25;
                    server.Send(myEmail);
```

my webconfig:

```
system.net>
<mailSettings>
  <smtp deliveryMethod="Network">
    <network port="587" host="smtp.gmail.com"   enableSsl="true"   defaultCredentials="false" userName="yakov_mora@walla.c‏om" password="0545674811" />
  </smtp>
</mailSettings>
```

Please help!

Comment: may be gmail ports are closed? or password changed

Answer (score 0):

Don't add your username/password in public forums..
Anyway, remove the port

```
        myEmail.To.Add(new MailAddress("yakov_mora@gmail.com‏"));
        SmtpClient server = new SmtpClient();
        //server.Port = 25; not needed, remove this line
        server.Send(myEmail);
```